# Entity framework context has 0 results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, dbcontext

I am trying to make a call to my entity framwork model and get a result returned to my WCF service.

**WCF Service Method**

```
public User GetUser(string username, string password)
{
    User userProfile = null;
    try 
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            throw new Exception("Username and password is null or empty");
        }
        var context = new InventoryManagerEntities();
        var userContext = (from user in context.Users
            where
                user.usr_Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                user.usr_Password.Equals(password, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            select user).
            FirstOrDefault();

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw exception;
    }
    return userProfile;
}
```

This problem is my context has no data in each of the Entity object. so for instance user has 0 results but in SQL server i can see that i have data in my tables.

My Entity project is in a different project in the same solution by the way, i am not sure if that has to do with it.

**EF Project Connection String** 
i am using the same connection string in my WCF project too. The name of my Database in Sql Server Management Tool is `InventoryManager`

```
    <add name="InventoryManagerEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/InventoryManagerDBModels.csdl|res://*/InventoryManagerDBModels.ssdl|res://*/InventoryManagerDBModels.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=JUNIORLABOLD4A3\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=InventoryManager;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This could be a problem with your db context configuration. What happens if you do not filter by username and password, is the result empty sitll? If this is true, then your mapping is faulty and the error is on the entity project config.

Comment: I dont think that will change anything, i have tried using user.usr_Password == password syntax too and that doesnt return anything, the problem is the context has 0 count for all of my tables in the EF while there are data in the database itself @LuisBecerril

Comment: Why are you implementing your own (poor) authentication service? There's like 4 of them you could use that do proper password hashing and salting.  On top of it, you are comparing password in a case insensitive way?  Seriously?

Comment: @RobertMcKee that is not the point right now... i am just trying to return data with an input provided from the wcf

Comment: @ifelabolz sorry, i updated my comment

Comment: Add `throw new Exception(context.Users.Count());` and see what error you get. Or just put `return (new InventoryManagerEntities()).Users.First();` as the first line in your function.  Whichever is easier for you.

Comment: You are getting 0 rows because there is  none that satisfies your condition. As suggested above, first remove the condition and see if you are able to get some rows. Then you will work on fixing your condition.

Comment: @RobertMcKee hi, thanks for your help Robert. yeah i get "Sequence contains no elements" exception when i use return (new InventoryManagerEntities()).Users.First(); ... is this a problem in my EF project ?

Comment: Unknown, but it's not a problem with your code here at least.

Comment: @RobertMcKee what will be your place to look ?

Comment: Your implementation of InventoryManagerEntities.  Is it possible your code is looking for a configuration setting that is local to your project that isn't set? Like a connection string?  Or is it a repository by default that you haven't put any data into?

Comment: The first thing I would check is that the connection string for InventoryManagerEntities context is pointing to the right DB (the same you say has data in it).

Comment: @FrancescCastells I have added the connection string that i am using, does this look wrong ?

Comment: @RobertMcKee what i mean is there is data in my local database when i look in Sql Server Management studio, i have added the connection string i am using here, it is the same in my EF project and my WCF project... I still cant spot what i am doing wrong and why the data are not pulled through

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the ConnectionString to every of your projects. Either in Web.config or App.config.

If your Project doesn't have one of these two files, just create it. but I am sure that the project, which doesn't load any results, has a different connectionString as the Entity-Project.

You have to know that MVC-Projects mostly do create a connectionString automatically. Check it!